# TcpListener waiting for client and a queue is processed at the same time

Tags: c#

I have a TcpListener, waiting for a client, who sends hin an order. When he gets the order, a generator generates a new file. This takes a while and only one object of generator can work at the same time. So I like to make a queue of orders, put the new order in the queue and close the connection to the client again. So the programm can get a lot of orders in a short time but needs time to process them.

I want that my programm is processing my queue like the methode StartGenerator, but how can I let my listener waiting for the client requests and still process orders, when there are orders in the queue?

```
 class Program
{
    private static Queue<Order> requestList = new Queue<Order>();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, port);
        listener.Start();
        StartGenerator();
        while (true)
        {
            TcpClient client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
            //Adds the order from the client to the Queue
            AddOrder(client);
        }
    }

    private static void StartGenerator() {
        while (true) {
            if (generateRequestList != null && generateRequestList.Count != 0) {
                Order currentOrder = generateRequestList.Dequeue();
                Generator generator = new Generator(currentOrder);
                while (!File.Exists(resultFileFromGenerator))
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(10000);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a classic "Producer–consumer problem" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer%E2%80%93consumer_problem

Comment: You should be using Asynchronous events to read TCP.  See msdn samples : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/socket-code-examples.  The Waitone can be used to synchronize your queues.